# Unity3D Digital Joystick for cursor movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey im pretty new in c#,
im building a plane sim and on the pc you can control the plane with the cursor through mouse movement.
now i want an digital joystick on mobile device, so i can control the plane on that.
does anybody have an idea how to code that?
thx

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a tutorial online. A quick google search leads to [this video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjF3f60ve36AhVfhP0HHRH9CUUQwqsBegQICxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dzd75Jq37R60&usg=AOvVaw3jCfFz7MsY2vcXsSJRohAT) and hundreds more. On the asset store there are multiple controllers already made, for example [this one made by Unity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/starter-assets-third-person-character-controller-196526), which includes everything you need.

Next time, before asking a question, try to google what you need, 99 times out of 100 the thing you're trying to achieve has already been made over and over again ;)

Comment: i tryed google, but the links you posted is not the problem i have.
i want to have a joystick to control the mouse cursor, and not the character like wasd
i found nothing to this topic